# Website Fails after move from Dev to Production Oracleconnection exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

Our Asp.net/Vb.net (.net 4) site fails to load when moved from dev to production.
Works with no problems on Dev

(Dev is Windows 7 32-bit)

(Production is Server 2008 64-bit)

APP Pool is .NET v4.0, 32-Bit = True, PipeLine Mode = Integrated

The site connects to an Oracle 11g database via ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2)
The same version has been installed on Production as well.

We use TNSNAMES, it has been tested on Production and works.

Bellow is the error that I receive.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Unhandled Execution Error 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[OracleException (0x80004005)]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable) +1601
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +61
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +5329
   cpsweb.com.clsDB.Get_DataTable(String sSQL) in D:\SourceVaultLocal\WebSites\cpsweb.com\CPS_Code\clsDB.vb:42
   cpsweb.com.clsSec_Security.isVisible(String sPageName, Object& oObj) in D:\SourceVaultLocal\WebSites\cpsweb.com\CPS_Apps\Sec_WebSite\Code\clsSec_Security.vb:50
   cpsweb.com._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\SourceVaultLocal\WebSites\cpsweb.com\Default.aspx.vb:20
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1016
```

Comment: I am pretty new to Oracle myself, but one thing to check is your reference to the Oracle dll in your application. Make sure that reference exists on the production machine as well. Not sure if it is in GAC or if you are bringing along a dll. That is at least what broke my first .Net to Oracle application.

Comment: i also just saw, your dev machine is 32 bit, and production is 64 bit. I believe the Oracle dll is specific to 32/64

Comment: @mmeasor I do not believe it matters which type you use.  You must copy the version of the dll to the prod machine that you used on the dev machine.  This is also the reason that IIS has the 32-Bit flag on the application pool.  And also the reason visual studio gives you the option for target machine.  But for the sake of checking.  I've copied the 64 bit version of dll to the /bin directory and it still has the same error.